# Is it correct voice leading to move the same right hand chord shape down in contrary motion to the bass?

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

Here is a progression I wrote where you can see the right hand just moves down playing the same chord shape in CM to the bass. Is this good voice leading or is using 2 chords in the right hand with the same intervals a bad thing?

Answer (score 4):

This is okay. As long as you're avoiding parallel fifths, moving chords like this is not only permitted, but it's fairly routine.

What is odd about the progression is not the movement, but the second chord. A more expected progression would have D in the bass.